# If $A \subset B$ and $C \subset D$ then how can i prove $(A \cup C) \subset (B \cup D)$?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

$A$ is a subset of $B$ and $C$ is a subset of $D$ then how can I prove $A \cup C$ is a subset of $B \cup D$?

Comment: What is the real question? The one from the title or the one from the body?

Comment: I corrected the body

Comment: You haven't shown any work.  Please see [this article](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question/27933#27933) on mathSE query guidelines.

Comment: I search for this question but didn't find an answer so I asked. It's obvious. How can I show my work? I am new to set theory so I didn't have any support other than the internet.

Comment: @stackaayush It is good if you are learning on your own, what do you know if $A \subset B$?

Comment: I am getting all other than answer. And even downvotes. But not surprised!

Comment: No one here wants to do your homework for you. Show some effort.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let x ∈ A∪C, that means x ∈ A  or  x ∈ C.

If x ∈ A then x ∈ B since A⊂B

If x ∈ C then x ∈ D since C⊂D

In either case, x ∈ A∪C means x ∈ B∪D.

so,(A U C) ⊂ (B U D).

Answer (score 1):

I suppose you are new to math, welcome aboard!

When proving statements with the title "Prove that *A* is subset of *B*", the normal thing to do is to begin the proof with

> let $x\in A$
>
> ...(some logic)
>
> therefore $x \in B$

Than here the first line in your proof should be:

> Let $ x\in A \cup C$

The next thing to do is to continue step by step with exact definitions
In your case

> Than, by the union definition, $x\in A$ **or** $x\in C$
>
> If $x \in A$....

and so on.

Hope that's Enough :-)

However, in this level of learning exercising in your own is very encouraged and important ❗

Comment: That's so interesting, how you explained. Yeah, It's all good, I have to start from "x∈A  or x∈C" and so on. But I tried and still don't getting my answer to prove LHS and RHS. That's why I am writing a question here. I would really appreciate it if you had solved the whole.

Comment: You are almost there. If $x\in A$ than $x\in B$, because A contained in B. Also if I were you I would try this with an example or to draw some venn diagrams